# Как сделать вокруг кнопки ободок?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qpushbutton

Есть приложение, проблема в том, что я хочу сделать вокруг кнопки ободок. К примеру красного цвета (типа за кнопкой нарисовать прямоугольник немного больше кнопки), но я не понимаю  какие команды в *PyQt5* нужны чтобы рисовать прямоугольники. 
Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout,                         
QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QMessageBox
from random import*


app = QApplication([])
main_win = QWidget()

main_win.setWindowTitle('Fast Clicker')
main_win.resize(800,500)
main_win.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(100,200, 255)")
button1 = QPushButton()
button2 = QPushButton()
button3 = QPushButton()
button4 = QPushButton()
button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")
button2.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")
button3.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")
button4.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")
button1.setFixedSize(100,125)
button2.setFixedSize(100,125)
button3.setFixedSize(100,125)
button4.setFixedSize(100,125)

line = QVBoxLayout()
lineH1 = QHBoxLayout()
lineH1.addWidget(button1, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
lineH1.addWidget(button2, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
lineH1.addWidget(button3, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
lineH1.addWidget(button4, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)

main_win.setLayout(line)
line.addLayout(lineH1)
main_win.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чаще всего используют [StyleSheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html)

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, \
    QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QMessageBox
from random import*


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Fast Clicker')
        self.resize(800,500)
        
        button1 = QPushButton()
        button2 = QPushButton()
        button3 = QPushButton()
        button4 = QPushButton()
        
        h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        h_layout.addWidget(button1)
        h_layout.addWidget(button2)
        h_layout.addWidget(button3)
        h_layout.addWidget(button4)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addLayout(h_layout)


Stylesheet = '''
QWidget {
    background-color:rgb(100,200, 255);
}
QPushButton {
    background-color: #D98C00;
    min-width:  96px;
    max-width:  96px;
    min-height: 96px;
    max-height: 96px;
    border-radius: 48px;        /* круглый */
    border: 2px solid #09009B;
}
QPushButton:hover:pressed {
    background-color: red;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #0ff;
    border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet) 
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам Большое. А вы можете ещё подсказать как сделать так чтобы рандомно в каждом кругу отображалось слово CLICK. И если на него нажимают то оно подсвечиваэться зелёним и если нажал не туда то красным

Comment: @NikitaKhistov если текущий вопрос решен и если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить его как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас возникают другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS** *стиль*

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize


custom_button = """
QPushButton#Button {
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 5px solid #4CAF50;
}

QPushButton#Button:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen; /* Green */
  color: black;
}
"""

class ExampleCustomButton(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(QSize(180, 120))

        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(box)

        self.button_print_message = QPushButton("Напечатать сообщение", objectName="Button")
        self.button_print_message.clicked.connect(self.button_print_message_click_handler)
        self.button_print_message.setStyleSheet(custom_button)

        box.addWidget(self.button_print_message)

    def button_print_message_click_handler(self):
        print('Hello, World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ecb = ExampleCustomButton()
    ecb.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```